# Is it normal for SQL Paging to take Longer (x15~x20) than Getting All Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pagination, sqlperformance

I have View with around 16k Rows and it takes around 5 Seconds to Get All Data.

I've decided to implement "loading" into application so GUI wouldn't freeze and user would be able to work/look with/at provided data in DataGridView.

I've noticed that if I use SQL Paging for Getting All Data it takes around 90 Seconds(1,5 Minutes) so it's counterproductive.

Now I wonder if it's normal and why would anyone use it if it is?

I've tried 3 ways of SQL Paging:

> I'm using 160 for testing purposes!

```
DECLARE @int_percentage AS INT = 1

WHILE @int_percentage <= 100
BEGIN
    SELECT O.*, P.Percentage
    FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithComments O
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AppointmentID, NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY AppointmentID) Percentage
                FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithoutComments) P ON P.AppointmentID = O.AppointmentID
    WHERE P.Percentage = @int_percentage

    SET @int_percentage = @int_percentage + 1
END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @int_percentage AS INT = 1, @int_appointmentID AS INT = 0

WHILE @int_percentage <= 100
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 160 *
    FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithComments
    WHERE AppointmentID > @int_appointmentID

    SET @int_percentage = @int_percentage + 1
    SET @int_appointmentID = @int_appointmentID + 161
END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @int_percentage AS INT = 1, @int_currentStartingRowIndex AS INT = 1

WHILE @int_percentage <= 100
BEGIN
    EXEC spGetRows @int_startingRowIndex = @int_currentStartingRowIndex, @int_maxRows = 160

    SET @int_percentage = @int_percentage + 1
    SET @int_currentStartingRowIndex = @int_currentStartingRowIndex + 160
END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT *
FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithComments
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetRows] 
(
    @int_startingRowIndex INT,
    @int_maxRows INT
)
AS

DECLARE @int_firstID INT

-- Getting 1'st ID
SET ROWCOUNT @int_startingRowIndex
SELECT @int_firstID = AppointmentID FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithoutComments ORDER BY AppointmentID

-- Setting ROWCOUNT to MAX
SET ROWCOUNT @int_maxRows

-- Getting all data >= @int_firstID
SELECT *
FROM vAppointmentDetailsWithComments
WHERE AppointmentID >= @int_firstID

SET ROWCOUNT 0

GO
```

With results:
[image: Results]

Tables and Views Creation and Filling data:

> `FOR XML PATH` in "vAppointmentDetailsWithComments" is main performance
>   problem

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointment](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Appointment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Appointment] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Appointment_Number]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Number]
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comment](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Appointment_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Comment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Appointment] FOREIGN KEY([Appointment_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Appointment] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_Appointment]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Comment_Text]  DEFAULT (N'Some random Comment for Testing purposes') FOR [Text]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Comment_Time]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [Time]
GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vAppointmentDetailsWithComments]
AS
SELECT A.ID AppointmentID, (K.Comments + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) Comment
FROM Appointment A LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT A.ID,
        (SELECT STUFF
            ((SELECT REPLACE(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + K.Text, CHAR(7), '')
        FROM Comment K
        WHERE K.Appointment_ID = A.ID
        AND K.Text != ''
        ORDER BY K.Time FOR XML PATH, TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')) Comments
    FROM Appointment A) K ON K.ID = A.ID

GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vAppointmentDetailsWithoutComments]
AS
SELECT A.ID AppointmentID
FROM Appointment A

GO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT ON 
BEGIN TRAN 
DECLARE @int_appointmentID AS INT = 1,
         @int_tempComment AS INT
WHILE @int_appointmentID <= 16000 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO Appointment VALUES (@int_appointmentID)

    SET @int_tempComment = 1

    WHILE @int_tempComment <= 5
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Comment (Appointment_ID) VALUES (@int_appointmentID)

        SET @int_tempComment = @int_tempComment + 1
    END

SET @int_appointmentID = @int_appointmentID + 1 
END 
COMMIT TRAN

GO
```

Execution plans:
[Fast(FetchAll)](http://www.filedropper.com/fastfetchall)
[Slow(Top)](http://www.filedropper.com/slowtop)

Comment: Not sure how I could answer a questions with comments and variable names in Polish

Comment: @Andomar I don't know why does Variable names and comments matter, but never the less I've replaced Croatian with English for Your pleasing.

Comment: @Djiber, please include the version of SQL Server you are using.  SQL 2012 introduced the `OFFSET` clause of `ORDER BY` to facilitate T-SQL base pagination.  However, I would first ensure the view query is fully optimized as throwing pagination on top of it will make matters worse.  Please post your view, `CREATE TABLE` statements, and indexes.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've added SQL-SERVER-2008 Tag and Creation of `TABLE`s and `VIEW`s to original question, thank You for pointing that out.
I'm aware of `OFFSET` in SQL Server 2012, unfortunately we can't upgrade so I couldn't test that example.

About "pagination making matters worse":
How much worse?
Is there a point in using it when Getting All Data?
If it's not, when should I use it (except if only small part of data is needed)?

Comment: Please provide the execution plans for the "fast" case (fetch all) and at least one "slow" case (TOP would be my first choice). http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/getting-an-execution-plan#ap-explain-mssql-tab I guess you should see the difference there. It's probably that your "fetch page" queries tempted the optimizer to use an index which is actually bad.

Comment: @Djiber, thanks for the scripts.  Regarding how much worse pagination can make things, the first method you posted will require touching the same appointment row many times as the user pages through the data set.  A total of 808,000 appointment rows would be touched compared to 16,000 with a single pass.  I think rendering the first page of results while the query continues running the background would be preferable to pagination in this case.

Comment: @MarkusWinand I've added Execution plans (as links for download because I don't know how to add them otherwise) of generated (English) version of Queryes and notice that there's `Missing Index (Impact 13.617): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Name of Missing Index, sysname,>] ON [dbo].[Comment] ([Appointment_ID]`. I'm not getting that warning with actual (Croatian) version even though they both perform same. Also I didn't notice much difference between "Fast" and "Slow" (Except "Slow" is called 100 times)

Comment: @DanGuzman I'm not quite sure I understand (This is my 1'st Pagination attempt). I would like to shorten Pagination Fetching Time of All Data if it's possible, if it's not I'll replace Pagination with getting All Data because waiting for All Data so much longer is just counterproductive (Problem is because user wants to use data ASAP).

Comment: @Djiber, getting all 16K rows at once should be sub-second if you performance the concatenation in the application code.  Is that not fast enough for your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the performance issue is because there is no index on the Comment table Appointment_ID column.  With a clustered index on Appointment_ID and changing the primary key index to non-clustered, the select query from vAppointmentDetailsWithComments elapsed time reduced from about 5 seconds down to about 3.5 on my test box.  Below is a script to create the clustered index and recreate the primary key as a non-clustered index.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Comment DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Comment_Appointment;

ALTER TABLE Appointment DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Appointment;

ALTER TABLE Appointment ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Appointment
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(ID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.Comment 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Comment_Appointment FOREIGN KEY(Appointment_ID)
    REFERENCES dbo.Appointment (ID);


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_Comment_Appointment_ID ON Comment(Appointment_ID);
GO
```

The string concatentation of comments is an expensive operation to perform in T-SQL.  I suggest you do that on the application side, which I expect would be sub-second for 16K rows.  That would avoid the need to jump through hoops on the SQL side with a simple join to comments:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vAppointmentDetailsWithIndividualComments
AS
SELECT A.ID AppointmentID, K.Text, K.Time
FROM dbo.Appointment A 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Comment K
        ON K.Appointment_ID = A.ID
        AND K.Text <> '';
GO

SELECT AppointmentID, Text, Time
FROM dbo.vAppointmentDetailsWithIndividualComments
ORDER BY Time;
GO
```

Regarding the pagination techniques you listed, the first will perform progressively poorer further into the result set due to the scan of Appointments.

The query second is missing the `ORDER BY Appointment_ID`.  `ORDER BY` is required with `TOP` for deterministic results.  However, this method does have merit from a pagination performance perspective because it will perform a index seek on the Appointment table, providing consistent performance regardless of the position within the result set.

`SET ROWCOUNT` is deprecated but the bottom line is that is will perform similarly to the first query (progressively worse).

Comment: Thank You for provided Advices and Testing Results. Like I've mentioned in answer to @MarkusWinand `Missing Index` occurs only in Generated (English) version (Even though I don't know why neither how to change PK Index to Non-Clustered so I would appreciate if You could explain that part).